# C - File management, unable to obtain desired output

Tags: c, arrays, string, file-management

I am working on my school assignment and I've come across my first major hurdle... I am unable to write to a file or even retrieve input using scanf and fgets.

Problem 1:

```
FILE *f1;
char date_trans[100][15];
    f1 = fopen("test.txt", "w");

if (f1 == NULL)
    printf("File could not be opened.\n");

else
    printf("Enter details (sender, receiver, amount.)\n");

    for(i = 0; i <= element; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j <= 20; j++)
            fgets(date_trans[i][j], 15, stdin);
            printf("%s", date_trans[i][j]);
    }
    fclose(f1);
```

This is a small snippet; with the above code I am unable to retrieve the input entered and print it out on display/to a file.

My intent is to have 100 strings and up to 15 characters each.

So say if I were to enter a date like 18/12/15 or like 18-12-15, or a word like "Daniel", the program stops abruptly for a few seconds after I press enter and then proceeds to display "Press any key...".

I also receive this error...

`` [Warning] ...\assignment\test.c:22: warning: passing arg 1 of `fgets' makes pointer from integer without a cast ``

which I really do not understand as the variable date_trans is a string/an 2d array of characters, not an integer, right?

---

Edit:

Problem 2:

```
    for (j=0; j <= 50 || !feof(f1); j++); // f1 opened in 'r' mode.
        {
            fscanf(f1, "%s %d %s %d %s %f", date_trans[j], &accsend[j], accnames[j],
            &accreceive[j], accnamer[j], &amount_trans[j]);
            printf("%d %s %d %s %d %s %.2f\n", j+1, date_trans[j], accsend[j], accnames[j], 
            accreceive[j], accnamer[j], amount_trans[j]); 
        }
```

In the code above, I am trying to input data through the stream f1 with function fscanf, which was opened in read mode. However the output makes the program hang and I am also unable to type or do any actions within the program.

As well, please advise whether my usage of !feof is correct/appropriate.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `date_trans[i][j]` is a `char`, not a `char *`

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hi, thanks for commenting. Could you elaborate on why date_trans[i] is a char* but date_trans[i][j] is not?

Comment: you need brackets for the 'else' statement. Identation ist not enough!

Comment: And brackets in the "for j" loop to enclose the fgets and printf statements. This isn't Python!

Comment: `date_trans` is an array of strings. `date_trans[i]` is one string and so points to the chars that make up the string. The compiler interprets it as a pointer to char.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see ***two*** problems with the code you show:

1. The warning you get, because `date_trans[i][j]` is a `char`, not a `char *`
2. Your inner loop goes from `0` to `20` (inclusive) and you use that as index into an array with 15 elements (i.e. indexes from `0` to `14` inclusive).

To solve both problems, don't have the inner loop, instead in the outer do

```
fgets(data_trans[i], sizeof data_trans[i], stdin);
```

Problem number 1 also exists in the `printf` call, where you pass a single `char` to a format that expects a `char *`.

Lastly a note about your requirement of strings containing 15 characters: Don't forget the null-terminator, and its need for a space in the array as well. That means you currently have place for ***14*** characters plus the terminator.

Comment: `fgets(data_trans[i], sizeof data_trans[i], f1);` --> `fgets(data_trans[i], sizeof data_trans[i], stdin);` OP intended to read in from `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks but I really don't get it still. I just read that char* is a pointer to a char so I don't understand why a 2d would be a char type instead of a char* type. It's really important that it is a 2d array as I need to read multiple strings.

Comment: @partynextdoor18 `data_trans` is of type `char [100][15]`. `data_trans[i]` is of type `char [15]`. And `data_trans[i][j]` is of type `char`. I.e. `data_trans[i][j]` isn't a "string", it's a single character.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, I'm aware of that. If so, how would I go about having an array of 100 rows 15 columns ([100][15]), so 100 strings with up to 15 characters each if not the method I employed in the main post?

Comment: @partynextdoor18 Like I said in my answer: Don't have the inner loop, and the shown `fgets` call instead.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I see, thanks. Could you give advice on my 2nd problem? I just added it to the post.

Comment: @partynextdoor18 That's a very different problem and should be asked as a different question. And please take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
    fgets(date_trans[i][j], 15, stdin);
    printf("%s", date_trans[i][j]);
```

to

```
    fgets(date_trans[i], 15, stdin);
    printf("%s", date_trans[i]);
```

`date_trans[i][j]` is `char` type not `char *`. Also you don't need `j` for loop.